# Как узнать id чата из BotKicked

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram

Бот отправляет сообщения в группы telegram, ID берет из БД, задача удалять из БД ID, если возникает BotKicked

Answer (score 1):

Раз ты получаешь такую ошибку, значит ты используешь:

```
bot.send_message(chat_id, text)
```

Нужно обрабатывать это исключение как-то так:

```
try:
    bot.send_message(chat_id, text)
except aiogram.utils.exceptions.BotKicked as error:
    # а здесь уже логика удаления строки с этим chat_id из твоей базы данных.
```

Comment: Исключение то обрабатываю, вопрос в том, как узнать chat_id которому не удалось отправить сообщение?

Comment: Раз ты передаешь в функцию bot.send_message chat_id, значит ты где-то хранишь его в переменной. Тогда тебе в except остаётся только сделать запрос в базу данных с этой же переменной.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    Отправка сообщения...
except BotKIcked:
    удаляем id из бд
```

я так себе это представляю